# Uninstalling a hidden program

Tags: uninstall, screen-sharing

In order to get technical support I had to allow a vendor to install "ScreenMeet" on my computer for remote support.  Now that the call is done I want to remove this software.  However, it seems to be hidden.  There is no uninstall option in add/remove programs (app does not appear) and I can't find it in programs files directories.

Does anyone know how to remove this app?

Comment: does it appear in one of the sub keys HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and does that key have an UninstalString value?

Comment: How do you know it was not uninstalled when the session was finished?

Comment: It's not in that branch of the registry, and (Greg) I can't be sure that it did not uninstall itself (or if it was a simple EXE without installation that deleted itself).  I just don't like/trust remote access programs that provide a stranger with open access to my pc